# Make: How to process many input files in one invocation of a tool?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a data conversion process that is driven by GNU make.  It takes human-generated input files and creates output files using a conversion progam.  Obviously this is about as simple as a makefile can get:

```
inputs=$(wildcard *.input)
outputs=$(subst .input,.output, $(inputs))

.PHONY: all
all: $(outputs)    

%.output: %.input
    converter $< -o $@
```

It gets even easier; `converter` knows the location of the output file from the input file, so we don't need `$@`:

```
%.output: %.input
    converter $<
```

So far, so good.  The problem is that `converter` takes a long time to start up compared with the amount of time to actually process one file.  If there are many files to process, there is a lot of wasted time.  I'd like to be able to execute `converter` once, passing in all members of `$(inputs)` **that require conversion**.

My current technique is to use `eval` to populate a list of all the input files that require conversion, and process that list in a later rule:

```
.PHONY: all
all: single_convert

.PHONY: single_convert
single_convert: $(outputs)
    converter $(newer_inputs)

%.output: %.input
    $(eval newer_inputs+=$<)
```

This feels like I'm fighting *against* make though, whereas makefiles normally feel very natural and helpful to me.

My question is; is there a better way?  Are there edge cases I've not considered?  Is what I'm doing dangerous?

Comment: For interest's sake; obviously my example was hypothetical.  In my actual use case the input and output files were PNG images, and the conversion program was the Unity3D editor (called from the command line) calling some custom processing code.  The Unity3D editor takes a few seconds to start up, whereas and the actual processing time was almost zero.  Another detail is that Unity3D cannot run in parallel, so "make -j" wasn't so important to me as it might be in other cases (usually I'm a big fan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to funnel all `.output` creation through a single run of `convert`. One way of achieving this is for each `.output` file to rely on a simply created `.intermediate` (say) file.

```
.DELETE_ON_ERROR: # You always want this

inputs := $(wildcard *.input)
intermediates := ${inputs:.input=.intermediate}
outputs := ${inputs:.input=.output}

${outputs}: single_convert

single_convert: ${intermediates}
    convert ${?:.intermediate=.input}
    touch $@

${intermediates}: %.intermediate: %.input
    touch $@

${outputs}: single_convert
```

(See [Empty Target Files to Record Events](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Empty-Targets) in the manual.)

This works nicely. From scratch:

```
$ touch 1.input 2.input 3.input
$ make
touch 2.intermediate
touch 1.intermediate
touch 3.intermediate
convert 2.input 1.input 3.input
touch single_convert
```

Incrementally. For instance, when just `1` and `2` are out of date:

```
$ touch 1.input 2.input
$ make
touch 2.intermediate
touch 1.intermediate
convert 2.input 1.input
touch single_convert
```

This is a bit of a hack though. You are lying to *make*, never a good idea (as in: you haven't told *make* how to build `file.output` say). Also, this formulation precludes the possibility of parallel operation using the `-j`*n* flag, which is the whole point of *make* IMHO.

This makefile is much simpler:

```
${outputs}: %.output: %.input
    convert $<

.PHONY: all
all: ${outputs}
```

with great performance if you have 8 CPUs say:

```
$ make -j 9 all
```

Comment: I don't think this is going to work unless you fake make out a bit more with a dummy `%.output: %.input` rule (or make will complain that it doesn't know how to generate the output files). You could do this by using `$(inputs)` in the prereq instead though (and it will convert and inputs newer than the stamp file.

Comment: @bobbogo Did you mean to write `single_convert: $(inputs)`?  I see what you're doing though.

Comment: Urk! Note to self: think more and type less. @EtanReisner is dead right of course. Will re-write.

Comment: Why bother with the intermediates? They don't record anything useful unless you want to support manually converting individual files and having make realize not to re-convert those the next time the `all` target is run (unless I've missed something).

Comment: Hmmm. You need a succinct way of telling _make_ that `1.output` depends on `1.input`. A static pattern rule fits the bill, but will only work iff it has a recipe that actually touches the output file. It's more than a little dangerous for the static pattern rule to simply touch `1.output`. The _convert_ command may later fail, and now you are left with a damaged file system: `1.output` exists, yet is not up-to-date. Very bad. The `.intermediate` formulation does not have this problem.

Comment: [Of course, instead of the static pattern rule you could do something like `$(foreach _,${inputs},$(eval ${_:.input=.output}: $_)`, but I was avoiding the use of `$(eval)` and doing it in pure _make_.]

Comment: This has been an interesting discusson.  The sentence "You are lying to make" is essentially the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

If I were in this situation, what I'd do is something like the following:

```
all: convert.stamp

convert.stamp: $(inputs)
  rm convert.stamp
  x= ; \
    for f in $(inputs:.input=); do \
      test $$f.output -nt $$f.input || x="$$x $$f.input"; \
      done; \
    converter $$x
  touch convert.stamp
```

That's quite similar to what you've done, except that the step of obtaining the list of out-of-date files is done in a shell action rather than by using fancy Make features.

There are a couple of reasons for that:

1. The `+=` syntax you've used is, I think, specific to GNU Make.  From long habit, I try to keep makefiles as portable as possible, and avoid make extensions as much as possible (I'm not religious about it, though: the `%.ext` syntax isn't in [POSIX Make](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html), but is nonetheless common and useful enough that it's perverse not to use it).  You've implied that you're happy to have a solution specific to GNU Make, so this reason won't have much traction with you.
2. Separately, it seems clearer to me to have the logic spelled out in this way: it means that each rule is more self-contained, whereas the `+=` device you've used means that the two rules interact in a non-obvious way.

These two points imply that I have a fairly high tolerance of complicated actions, and a low tolerance of complicated Make syntax – your tastes may vary.

*Key point*: You can't get away from *some* sort of complication of this type.  Make is fundamentally about updating files one at a time.  In (reasonably) wanting to collapse updates in this way, you are unavoidably subverting Make's model of working: we can't expect that to be natural.  That is, I don't think you or I are missing a trick.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The fact that nobody has replied with "Yes, make supports this, here's how" is, in itself, an answer to my question.